# Winform desktop app and touch

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-store-apps, touch

I`ve a legacy winform desktop app that works perfectly with mouse and keyboard. It has some selfmade controls that involve the creation of threads and so on, for example the longer a button is pushed the faster a number is incremented.

The application also uses a win32 dll. Now, the client wants that application to be touch enabled and run it in a tablet, which also means resizing and rotation capabilities.

My question is, which is the better way to get that application touch enabled and responsive design?

I can try to modify the existing winform, but I think it will be lot of work with poor results. I can also migrate to WPF and reuse the c# code, but I might have trouble with the keyboard, as I have not found a good way to show the keyboard and maintain the whole app on the screen. Or I can migrate to windows store app, but with the problem of that win32 dll, that I`m not sure it could be migrated.

The winform application is multilingual so creating a keyboard is not a valid option.

Comment: What is Win32.dll you mean system's dll or your own?

Comment: The Win32 dll is not system´s dll is my own.

Answer (score 0):

If the target is touch screen, then for sure the best option would be a Windows Store App, although there are several limitations.

If you are not going to publish this application in Windows Store, then you should be able to use all WinAPI functions. (I'm not sure what is win32.dll - if it's your own dll then it can be a problem).

Comment: The win32 dll is my own dll. I`m not going to publish it in the store, but I am worried about the Windows Store App limitations.